# which windows devices support beacon (Ranging and monitoring)?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, ibeacon, beacon

I am creating a mobile application that can detect iBeacons and I am confused which windows devices support that. I already checked that it's possible in Windows 10 but somewhere I read that it's also possible for Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to detect beacons with Windows Phone 8.x because the OS has no built-in beacon support and does not allow apps to access raw Bluetooth LE scan results.

You can read more info about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30603394/1461050

Comment: Thanks For your answer but for which devices it support on windows 10 devices only ??

Comment: I have not heard reports of any Windows 10 devices that do not support BLE beacon detection.  I believe all do at this time.

Comment: I have not heard reports of any Windows 10 devices that do not support BLE beacon detection.  I believe all do at this time.